# Run Shellcode/Machine Code and Input Arguments?

Tags: cryptography, reverse-engineering, shellcode, machine-code

I'm looking at a tool which sends some Shellcode for encryption, which I expect is used to generate a seed.

I have the Shellcode which is built for `x86` architecture. I know that the expected `function` of the code is to generate a seed from three 8 `byte` `integers`. However, I have no idea on how to proceed and generate the output from this... The numbers in this case are (as `integer`, not `hex`) 1095923727, 3459613537, and 2312051101.

The `hexdump` of the code looks like this:

```
5589 e583 ec18 c704 2410 0000 00e8 26ff
ffff 8945 f0c7 45f4 0000 0000 eb62 8345
f401 8b45 08f7 d0c1 e810 3345 0889 45f8
8b55 f48b 45f8 01d0 69c0 6745 2301 35ef
cdab 8989 4508 8b45 0831 450c 8b45 0801
4510 8b55 f48b 45f8 01d0 69c0 efcd ab89
3567 4523 0189 4508 8b45 0889 45f8 8b45
0c89 4508 8b45 1089 450c 8b45 f889 4510
817d f4ff 0000 0076 958b 550c 8b45 0831
d033 4510 8945 f88b 45f0 8945 fc8b 55fc
8b45 0889 028b 45fc 8d50 048b 450c 8902
8b45 fc8d 5008 8b45 1089 028b 45fc 8d50
0c8b 45f8 8902 8b45 f0c9 c3
```

Running that through decompiler yields something like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bmxPzmL.png]

How can I run the code above with the three `input` arguments and generate output?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the second time you posted this. The first time you posted it, when it was assembly language, it was closer to something usable. This looks like you tried to run it through some sort of Hexadecimal to ANSI C converter or something and it got mangled. That code doesn't make any sense.